# Extending ViewGroup with @EViewGroup annotation

Tags: android, inheritance, annotations, viewgroup, android-annotations

I am trying to implement something very common for web developers with android view groups and annotations.
The idea is to have basic `ViewGroup` that has its own layout basic. Like header, content  and footer.
All other view groups that have the same layout,but different content inside blocks have to extend this base `ViewGroup`.
For example my `BaseViewGroup`

```
@EViewGroup(R.layout.base_view_group)
public abstract class BaseViewGroup extends RelativeLayout {
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    @ViewById
    public RelativeLayout rlHeader;
    @ViewById
    public RelativeLayout rlFooter;
    @ViewById
    public RelativeLayout rlScrollMain;

    // Template methods for inflating dialog
    public abstract int getHeaderViewId();

    public abstract int getFooterViewId();

    public abstract int getScrollMainViewId();

    public CDialogBase(DialogChain dialogChain, Context context) {
        super(context);
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @AfterViews
    void afterViews() {
        rlHeader.addView(mLayoutInflater.inflate(getHeaderViewId(), rlHeader, false));
        rlScrollMain.addView(mLayoutInflater.inflate(getScrollMainViewId(), rlHeader, false));
        rlFooter.addView(mLayoutInflater.inflate(getFooterViewId(), rlFooter, false));
    }
}
```

And when we need concreate class we have to extend and implement template methods.

// @EViewGroup
    public class ConcreteViewGroup extends BaseViewGroup {

```
    @ViewById
    TextView textView;

    @ViewById
    Button button;

    @Override
    public int getHeaderViewId() {
        return R.layout.concrete_header;
    }

    @Override
    public int getFooterViewId() {
        return R.layout.concrete_footer;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollMainViewId() {
        return R.layout.concrete_main;
    }

    @AfterViews

    @Click

    @Click
  ......
}
```

So I need to extend base ViewGroup and provide concreate resources in template methods. And than in inherited concrete class also use annotations for finding view and other stuff.
I have  got an error because my inherited class is not annotated, but if annotate it, it will crash because I have to provide layout in annotation.

Is it possible to have something like I've described above ?
Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Note: you can use `@SystemService` for the injection of `LayoutInflater`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the layout in the subclass as well :  `@EViewGroup(R.layout.base_view_group)`.

Comment: Doesn't work as far as I know it will find only views in declared `@EViewGroup` but in inherited class I am passing header, footer and content in runtime

Comment: Yeah that's a problem. You can inflate the header etc in onCreate, but that way you cannot use the injected views, yet. This is a bad cycle. Or you can call the view notifier manually, as you can see in the generated code. But that is not a good idea.